# Is there any way to upload local storage photos/videos into s3 buckets using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am quite new to AWS Service and I would like to know, is there any way to upload local storage photos/videos into s3 bucket using AWS Lambda function?
I knew that we can download s3 bucket data by using AWS Lambda function but can we upload photos/videos into s3 bucket using AWS Lambda?

Thanks,

Comment: Lambda does not run locally and cannot access local files natively. Why do you want to use Lambda for uploading files from local storage to S3?

Comment: I have to upload gallery photos/videos into s3 bucket. So I like to know is there any way to do this function.

Comment: Architecting a solution on AWS without actually knowing very much about AWS services is going to be challenging. Stackoverflow is not the right place to gain a high-level view of AWS services or how to architect mobile solutions. One good place to start would be https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-mobile.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Lambda for that:

You can upload local files from your system to S3 bucket using AWS Console or if you prefer command line you can use AWS CLI.

S3 CLI command for upload:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

For Application access you can use AWS SDKs for access to S3.

Comment: Yeah but I am making online gallery mobile app. So If more number of users want to upload their photos/videos in s3 bucket, will it available for all or degrade the performance without using Aws lambda?

Comment: s3 is a massively scaled service. so rest assured it will not degrade performace for user if you follow the right architecture. eg: Use AWS SDK in your mobilie app to directly upload to s3 without going thru your EC2/Lambda functions (to save both costs and performance bottlenecks). You can use AWS Cognito/STS to ensure authentication to the corresponding S3 bucket

Comment: Okay then where should I use AWS Lambda or where it can be useful? Any suggest.

Comment: Lambda is a "Serverless" construct, ie if you have some functionality to execute without provisioning an EC2 instance. It has few restrictions/limitations but largely much more cost efficient.

Some usecases:
1. Creating Microservices architecture with API gateway in front.
2. Some Event based processing of some functionality. eg: SNS triggers, CloudWatch triggers, DynamoDB etc
3. House keeping functions eg: eviction of caches etc.

Could you accept my above answer if it answered your original question?